# Sum the amount on trailing1-2months only when trailing2-4months is not null in Superset

Tags: sql, apache-superset

I want to Calculate Net Dollar Retention on an account level, with product level filters on the dashboard. NDR on this case is defined as the sum of trailing 2 months for an account that has purchased in the last 3-4 months ago. for example, if we are standing in March, client "A" purchased a contract but he had also purchased a contract in January, so his NDR should be 1000.50

Here's an example of the Table I am using

| account_id | product_name | sales_month_year | trailing1-2months | trailing3-4months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Product A | 2024-01-01 | 1000.50 | NULL |
| a | Product A | 2024-02-01 | 1000.50 | NULL |
| a | Product A | 2024-03-01 | NULL | 1000.50 |
| a | Product A | 2024-04-01 | NULL | 1000.50 |
| a | Product A | 2024-05-01 | 1800.90 | 1000.50 |
| a | Product C | 2024-03-01 | 2000.75 | NULL |
| a | Product C | 2024-04-01 | 2000.75 | NULL |
| a | Product C | 2024-05-01 | NULL | 2000.75 |
| b | Product B | 2024-02-01 | 1500.25 | NULL |
| b | Product B | 2024-03-01 | 1500.25 | NULL |
| b | Product B | 2024-04-01 | NULL | 1500.25 |
| b | Product B | 2024-05-01 | NULL | 1500.25 |
| b | Product D | 2024-04-01 | 1200.80 | NULL |
| b | Product D | 2024-05-01 | 1200.80 | NULL |

When I try to calculate NDR in Superset, I can only calculate it at the account and product level (row per row), I created the following metric.

`sum(case when trailing3-4months is not null then trailing1-2months)`

But this won't work because it will calculate each row individually. in the example above, I won't have NDR for account "A" in march because his 2 purchases happened on different products. I want to create a bar chart that will sum column trailing1-2months when the client, regardless of the product, purchased on trailing2-4months.

Having the product details is still necessary because I would like the user to have the ability to filter by product in the dashboard

[image: Superset NDR Bar Graph]
This would be what I am looking for, a graph in superset that will give me NDR on the account level. I can't give a tabular example of the table output I need because I don't know if there is a table structure that will accomplish this. I am thinking (hoping I am wrong) that I will need to use jinja templating

Comment: It'd help if you also provided your expected result, in the same tabular format as you've provided the input.

Comment: Hi @Error_2646. Thanks for your comment. I don't really know what table structure would work here. An approach that would work is if I aggregate only by account, which will give the the right result, the issue is that I will then loose the ability to filter by product